# Insert values into certain rows in mySQL database from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

yesterday I created my first database (very simple, 2 columns), I've just written a php page which can read the values. What I'm wanting to do now is write a front end that will allow me to change the values in certain rows of the database.
Here's a sample of what I have to read the database:

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:5002", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("sysstats") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
$SysData = mysql_query("SELECT Status FROM systemstatus") or die(mysql_error());

$SysArray = Array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($SysData, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $Statuses[] = $row['Status'];
    }

//put array in to variables
$GappsMail= $Statuses[0];
$GappsGroups= $Statuses[1];
$GappsCal= $Statuses[2];
$GappsDocs= $Statuses[3];
```

example of part of the body to show the database query from 1 result

```
<?  if ($GappsMail == "1")  {  ?>
  <div class ="green"></div>
  <?  }  else if ($GappsMail == "2")  {  ?>
  <div class ="amber"></div>
  <?  }  else  {  ?>
  <div class ="red"></div>
  <?  }  ?>
```

This is a small sample, in the database the column it's looking at (systemstatus) is a "1" but I want us to be able to change this between 1, 2 and 3 using radio buttons or a drop down, however I'm still learning php as I go, I'm not sure of the best way to write to a database, all the examples I find online seem to want to write to every row, where as I may only need to write to, for example, row 45 and leave all the other rows alone. Can anyone recommend the best way to do this?

```
<form>
Google Apps - Mail
<input type="radio" name="GappsMail" value="1">G<br>
<input type="radio" name="GappsMail" value="2">A<br>
<input type="radio" name="GappsMail" value="3">R<br>

Google Apps - Calendar
<input type="radio" name="GappsCal" value="1">G<br>
<input type="radio" name="GappsCal" value="2">A<br>
<input type="radio" name="GappsCal" value="3">R<br>
</form>
```

thanks

Comment: Note that this method (mysql_) is deprecated. See PDO and/or mysqli_, sql injection, as well as prepared statements

Comment: Read documentation about `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, managed to solve it so thought I'd put up what I did incase anyone ever looks in future

the form page looks like this (2 questions as an example):

```
<form action="./ChangeStatusSubmit.php" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="GappsMailS" value="1"><font color="green">G </font><input type="radio" name="GappsMailS" value="2"><font color="orange">A </font><input type="radio" name="GappsMailS" value="3"><font color="FF0000">R</font>

<input type="radio" name="GappsGroupsS" value="1"><font color="green">G </font><input type="radio" name="GappsGroupsS" value="2"><font color="orange">A </font><input type="radio" name="GappsGroupsS" value="3"><font color="FF0000">R</font>
<button type="submit" >
Submit status changes
</button>
```

the ChangeStatusSubmit.php page looks like this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:5002", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("sysstats") or die(mysql_error()) ;

if ($GappsMailS != ""){ mysql_query("UPDATE systemstatus SET Status='$GappsMailS' WHERE SysName='GappsMail'");}
if ($GappsGroupsS != ""){ mysql_query("UPDATE systemstatus SET Status='$GappsGroupsS' WHERE SysName='GappsGroups'");}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly since you learning you should start off on the right foot. Scrap your mysql commands and use mysqli. The mysql class is deprecated.

Secondly Look here for the basics of php and mysqli [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) It should get you on the right track

Comment: There is a next chaper button at the bottom right to proceed through the tutorial. Lots of people miss it, just thought i should give you heads up

Comment: More a comment than an answer. Please do not just post a tutorial link but explain at least basics (insert and updates) with an example. What if w3schools close tomorrow ?

Comment: @OlivierH Valid. Point taken

Comment: Cheers guys, however I'm updating a very old system that already has the DB commands in and I'm up against time, right now I cannot change to the newer commands, I cannot even update from php 4.4 which is on there!
Once Feb comes around I will have the opportunity to re-write everything from scratch

Comment: You will either need to use POST or GET to push that info across. If you want it to happen as they click the radio button you will need to have a look at ajax or jquery. So first thing would be to look at the $_POST and $_GET.